# When to use a Float

Tags: c#, types, floating-point

Years ago I learned the hard way about precision problems with floats so I quit using them.  However, I still run into code using floats and it make me cringe because I know some of the calculations will be inaccurate.

So, when is it appropriate to use a float?

**EDIT:**
As info, I don't think that I've come across a program where the accuracy of a number isn't important.  But I would be interested in hearing examples.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Short answer: You only have to use a **float** when you know exactly what you're doing and why.

Long answer: **floats** (as opposed to **doubles**) aren't really used anymore outside 3D APIs as far as I know. Floats and doubles have the same performance characteristics on modern CPUs, doubles are somewhat bigger and that's all. If in doubt, just use double.

Oh yes, and use **decimal** for financial calculations, of course.

Comment: Many good answers... confirming my thoughts about accuracy and memory.  Most go with the Assistant to the Regional Manager though. :)

Comment: ...but don't use decimal for *real* financial calculations. It is *still* relative precision (albeit with a stupidly huge range and precision). Use an *appropriate library* that defines fixed-precision math to the smallest currency (could wrap a decimal) in question (mils, 1/1000$ for the USD) and knows how to handle cases such as "who gets the odd penny" and all the funny rounding rules.

Comment: "doubles are just somewhat bigger": usually about twice as big.

Answer (score 13):

All floating point calculations are inaccurature in a general case, floats just more so than doubles. If you want more information have a read of 
[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

As for when to use floats - they are often used when precision is less important than saving memory. For example simple particle simulations in video games.

Comment: To be honest, I struggle to imagine a particle engine having so many particles that using floats saves a considerable amount of memory. Well maybe on phones or other embedded devices. But then again, their CPU probably can't handle that many particles anyway.

Answer (score 9):

First, never use floats or doubles if you want to represent decimal values exactly - use either integer types (int, long etc) or decimal (which is just an integer type with a scaling factor). Floats and doubles are converted internally to an exponential representation in base 2 and numbers represented exactly in an exponential representation in base 10 cannot in general be represented exactly. (E.g., the number 10 is only represented approximately by floats or doubles).

Second, in terms of precision it depends on what you need. I don't agree with your sentiment that there are never calculations where precision does not matter. You normally have a specific need that your final result is accurate to say, 3 digits. It does not make sense to look for the highest precision possible if your input has only limited accuracy - say you weigh some 5g of flour and your scale only has an accuracy to 0.5g. That said, intermediate calculation usually benefit from higher precision but something that is more important than high precision if quite often speed.

Third, when preforming a series of calculations, say within a loop, you need to know what you are doing when dealing with any inexact calculations - you will incur round-off errors and some algorithms may not arrive at an answer to any degree of precision. Understanding these issues in detail may require a course in numerical analysis. This does not depend on whether you choose floats or doubles for your calculations.

For floating point calculations I would usually go with doubles since they are more general and faster than floats. However, floats are smaller and if you need to store a lot of them they are the choice to prevent performance issue due to cache misses.

To my knowledge, floating point processing is supported in hardware for doubles but not floats, so using floats incurs a conversion to double. However, some routines would stop sooner when calculating a value iteratively when you pass a float, since this implies that you only want about 8 digits precision vs. about 16 for doubles.

Comment: Actually, the number 10 (and all other integers up to 16777216) can be represented *exactly* as a float.

Answer (score 7):

There are many cases you would want to use a `float`. What I don't understand however, is what you can use instead. If you mean using `double` instead of `float`, then yeah, in most cases, you want to do that. However, `double` will also have precision issues. You should use `decimal` whenever the accuracy is important.

`float` and `double` are very useful in many applications. `decimal` is an expensive data type and its range (the magnitude of the largest number it can represent) is less than `double`. Computers usually have special hardware level support for those data types. They are used **a lot** in scientific computing. Basically, they are primary fractional data types you want to use. However, in monetary calculations, where precision is extremely important, `decimal` is the way to go.

Comment: Decimal isn't more accurate than float or double given equivalent precision.  It's just that we are more accepting of the inaccuracies of decimal because they're more familiar to us in day-to-day life.

Comment: It is far better to understand your accuracy requirements and choose a data type accordingly than to blindly "use `decimal` whenever the accuracy is important."

Comment: You guys are right. I hope that is not what I implied. I should point out that whenever I talked about precision or accuracy in this post, I meant accuracy of digits with respect to arithmetic on decimal representation of the numbers.

Answer (score 6):

The most common reason I could think of is to save space.  Not that this is often worth worrying about, but in some instances it matters. A float takes up half as much memory as a double, so you can get twice as many in the same space.  For example, I've had an array of numbers that was too big to fit into RAM as doubles but fit as an array floats.

Answer (score 5):

There is in fact one thing where it is still common to use floats aka
"single precision" with 32 bits: Graphic applications and printing.

The other reason are graphic cards with their GPUs. The smaller the datatype, the faster
the operation because less bits must be transported. Integer datatypes have problems
with High Dynamic Range Images: The eye is able to function over a luminosity range of
1: 10^13 and discerns ca. 4000 levels. So while integer datatypes can store the number of levels they are unable to store the background brightness while floats have no problems with that. In fact IEEE 754R allows a new "half precision" float with 16 bits and a 10 bit
mantissa which loses some precision but would allow an even greater speed.
OpenGL and DirectX e.g. use floats extensively.
The eye is very forgiving with artifacts, so no problem there.

All other media building on graphics are inheriting floats as convienient measure.
The mantissa has 24 bits allowing therefore 2^24 = 16,7 millions consecutive steps.
If you have a printer with 2000 dpi resolution, you still are able to print 213x213 m
sheets. More than enough precision.

Comment: OpenGL has an 8bit float as well ;-) But it has too small a precision/range for many cases (e.g. can cause banding up the wazoo).

Answer (score 3):

Use float for **performance and size**. If you can manage the precision loss.

While it is true that a modern processor takes the same amount of time to process single and double precision opertions, you can sometimes get *twice* the throughput if you use floats with SIMD (MMX/SSE/etc. on x86) instructions.

SSE registers are 128 bits wide, and can hold *4 floats* or *2 doubles*. Thus, if used correctly, you can do twice as many operations with floats as compared to doubles.

The size reduction (4 bytes instead of 8) becomes important when dealing with very large data sets (and size reduction usually improves performance as well due to caching, etc.)